# How to use mongoose in two packages?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, package, lerna

I'm using Lerna to handle multiple packages in my repo.

Basically, I have a package `@pkg/server` where my Node/Express App is and an other package `@pkg/model` where my mongoose Schemas reside.

My REST API is using some of the models, with an `import ModelA from '@pkg/model'`.

The problem is that both of these packages have `mongoose` as a dependency (the `@pkg/server` uses mongoose to establish a connection to the mongoDB server, and `@pkg/model` uses mongoose to define schemas and models).

In my server, whenever I try to call `ModelA.find(...)`, it just hangs forever. From the mongoose docs, it looks like I have to register a model to a mongoose connection and not to the mongoose object itself.

My first guess is to pass the connection object created by the server to the `@pkg/model` and then register the models to this connection object.

My question is, is this the right way to do it? Or is there a way to do something like (in the `@pkg/server`) `mongoose.loadSchemas(@pkg/model)` ?

Answer (score 0):

What I have ended up doing, is that I'm passing the connection to the package requiring `mongoose` thus sharing the connection between packages.

Some package can register models, an other one can make queries, etc...